# How to get "iCalUId" from Office365 connector in Microsoft Logic Apps?

Tags: outlook, azure-logic-apps, outlook-calendar

I have an Azure Logic App that consists in getting events info by a given Id. I use [Office365 Get Event Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/connectors/office365connector/#create-event-(v4)) but it doesn't retrieve iCalUId.

Remember that Outlook events have two "ids":

- id: Unique identifier in resource calendar.
- iCalUId: Unique identifier in ALL attendees calendar.

I need the last one.

Is there any way to obtain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be a little late for you, but for anyone else landing here iCalUid was added to the connector recently.

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/connectors/office365connector/#graphcalendareventclientreceive